# How many bind variables can I use in a SQL query in MySQL 5?

Tags: mysql

Is there a limit to the number of bind variables I can use in a query in MySQL 5? I assume that there is, but I can't find any information in the reference manual or by Googling.

The only thing that I could find that provides any information at all is in the C API reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-bind-result.html

This seems to imply that memory is the only limit, but that seems a bit suspect.

**Update**: there is a limit!

```
runner.rb:47: data_replicator.rb:312:in `prepare': Prepared statement contains too many placeholders (Mysql::Error)
        from data_replicator.rb:312:in `set_statement_handle_for'
        from data_replicator.rb:287:in `log_query'
        from data_replicator.rb:221:in `replicate_table'
        from data_replicator.rb:93:in `replicate'
        from data_replicator.rb:20:in `run'
```

This gives me something better to search on!

Comment: Just curious, how many do you wish to pass? ;-)

Comment: As many as possible. :) What I'm trying to accomplish is moving certain data from a database on one server to a data warehouse-style database on another. I have a cascading series of queries, meaning I select records from one table which have IDs for records in another table, which I can then select by ID. I want to make my batches as large as possible, but no larger (to twist Einstein's advice).

Comment: You probably want a client API which simulates prepared statements on the client-side - it's generally more efficient and avoids such limits. However, for batch inserts, I'd probably go either with assembling large INSERT statements, or using LOAD DATA (LOCAL) INFILE.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I did eventually make my way to LOAD DATA INFILE. The large batch stuff still applies to my SELECTs, of course.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html :

> To guard against too many prepared
>   statements being created
>   simultaneously, set the
>   max_prepared_stmt_count system
>   variable.

According to the [max_prepared_stmt_count](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_prepared_stmt_count) documentation, the default is 16_382, and the permissible range is 0 (which disables prepared statements altogether), to 1_000_000.

Comment: This is the number of prepared statements, NOT the number of bind variables.

Answer (score 21):

The maximum number of placeholders for values in a prepared statement is the maximum value of a 16-bit unsigned integer, or specfically: 65,536.

This can be seen in the MySQL code here:
sql/sql_prepare.cc:

```
static bool init_param_array(Prepared_statement *stmt)
{
  LEX *lex= stmt->lex;
  if ((stmt->param_count= lex->param_list.elements))
  {
    if (stmt->param_count > (uint) UINT_MAX16)
    {
      /* Error code to be defined in 5.0 */
      my_message(ER_PS_MANY_PARAM, ER(ER_PS_MANY_PARAM), MYF(0));
      return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL is this? This code seems to contradict the documentation cited in my answer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: This is definitely true for the source tree of 5.1 as of 7/18/12, as I'm working with that code currently.

Comment: Just to add one more thing:  As was busy hacking away at mysql 5.1 anyways, I went ahead and changed the line mentioned in the answer to UINT_MAX32.  At first blush it seems to "just work."  So I'm not sure why the limit was there in the first place.

Comment: With this answer I was able to look up and [confirm the same for MariaDB 10.5](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.5/sql/sql_prepare.cc#L2639), it's still 65,535. Wish this was mentioned in the docs somewhere!

Answer (score 7):

There is limit ***65,535*** (2^16-1) place holders in **MariaDB 5.5** which is supposed to have identical behaviour as **MySQL 5.5**.

Not sure if relevant, I tested it on PHP 5.5.12 using MySQLi / MySQLND.

Answer (score -2):

The [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_prepared_stmt_count) says the default limit is 16.382. And depending on the version there is a hard limit at 4.294.967.295 (>= MariaDB 10.3.6) or 1.048.576 (<= MariaDB 10.3.5).

Comment: The linked documentation is about the number of _prepared statements_, not about the number of _placeholders_ in a single statement.